# Navigating under lock screen windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, lockscreen

I have created an app in which I want the app to run under lock screen and it involves navigating between pages. The issue is, it gives me an error "cannot navigate under lock screen". Is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, when phone is locked, your app goes in background (if you're using background services) or gets deactivated. In this case page-navigation OR UI related tasks can't be performed. You may, however, run background tasks.

Comment: You can render UI elements under lock screen but one is unable to navigate to a different page. Also when screen is locked, app is not deactivated as Application_Deactivated event is not triggered. You may find this function in `App.xaml.cs`. It may be that app is sent to background but if that is true, how am I able to render UI items in my listbox even when the screen is locked?

Comment: Sorry, I disagree. I just wrote a code and tested on my device to confirm what I said and I'm correct. When lock screen appears, app gets deactivated. I wrote Debug.WriteLine(EventName) in each event i.e. App_Launching, etc.. and observed the output window.
Now, what you can do is: When your app is running and phone is locked, your app gets deactivated. But when user unlocks the phone, the first thing happens is your app is activated and brought forward. You can write the UI updating/page navigation code in this event. Put your code App_Activated event. Try it and let me know.

Comment: I have put a break point in Application_Deactivated function found in App.xaml.cs. When I lock my phone the function is not executed. I can say this because I have placed a break point there. Also on unlock Application_Activated is not triggered. I hope you and I are on the same track and not talking about different events :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes Milan,
We're talking about the same events, but in my case it hits the break-points as well as gives proper event name in Output window. I've used following code:

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("App Launching");
}
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("App Activated");
}
private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("App Deactived");
}
private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("App Closing");
}
```

I hope it helps. Let me know if still there is any issue.

Comment: correct. Till now it was not happening the same with me because I was using these two statements `PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;`
            `PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;` Now the breakpoint is triggered.

So you are right that app is sent to background. Thanks. Learned something out of this activity :)